# Grails input type="submit" icon with bootstrap?

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, forms, glyphicons

I'm trying to get an icon in a submit button using GRAILS. I had resolved getting the button to display, but at the expense of the form throwing errors. To display the tags I did a button tag, but then the form throws this error:

```
--> sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()  -->AbstractInstanceController.groovy
        Cannot insert NULL into ("APP"."INSTANCE"."STATUS")
--> def instance = super.save(specificInstance, 'specificInstance.label') -->specificInstanceController.groovy
```

And the button in the gsp:

```
<button type="submit" name="_action_save" class="btn" value="Save">
    <i class="icon-folder-open"></i> Save
</button>
```

Does anyone know of a way to add an icon to an:

```
<input type="submit" ...>
```

or a way of fixing the grails errors being thrown using the

```
<button>
```

method?

**UPDATE**

```
<g:form name="form">
    <g:hiddenField name="status" />
    <g:hiddenField name="locationID" value="${instance?.location?.id}" />

<div class="formButtons">
    <g:actionSubmit value="Save" name="save_button" class="button cancel" action="save" data-icon="check" />
    <input type="submit" name="_action_save" value="Save" class="button cancel" action="save"/>
</div>

<g:render template="form"/> 
... "form" has many, many fields in the form of:
    <label for="section">Section</label>
    <g:textField name="section" class="textfield required" value="${instance?.section}"/>
```

Controller logic is the default save() scaffold with very few modifications:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
def save = {
    def instance = new Instance(params)
    instance.setDescription("instancePE")
    if(instance.instanceEnd == null){
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'instance.time.null.message', args: [instance.mode.instanceHours])}"
        render(view: "create", model: [instance: instance])
        return
    }

    if (!validStartEnd(instance)) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'instance.invalidRange.message', args: [instance.mode.instanceHours])}"
        render(view: "create", model: [instance: instance])
        return
    }

    instance.activeInstanceArchive =
        g.render(template: "/templates/showInstances",model:
                [loc: instance.instLocation])

        def inst = super.save(instance, 'instance.label')
        render(view: "create", model: [instance: inst])
}
```

Domain object is large, but does not have anything unusual about it. It simply lists the objects to store.

Comment: I had thought about making a custom tagLib for actionSubmit but the actionSubmit taglib already uses the input type="submit" html tag, so I'm not sure of a work around for that. I also noticed that this link for a button generator also doesn't give you the option of adding an icon to an input type="submit".... http://www.plugolabs.com/twitter-bootstrap-button-generator/

Comment: The type of button really should make 0 difference to your server side code.

Comment: @user2312990, just forget about the icon for now, can you successfully save? as James said this cannot be related to button. Unless you are missing a required param, if you can post the controller action, the form that is sending the request, and maybe the domain that stores the data.

Comment: that was my thought as well, but if I use <g:actionSubmit or <input type="submit", everything works fine... If I use <button> I get the error

Comment: Show the FULL html for the input that works and the button that doesn't.

Comment: what is `def instance = new instance(params)` ? if instance is domain name why do you have variable with the same name? notice that domain classes or all classes usually start with capital letter.

Comment: typo, apologies. I have edited the code to reflect the correct version. The real issue comes when it tries to flush the session.